# How to define margins of a document with page numbering at a specified place

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering

I have to follow specific rules for an A4 document:

- upper and lower margins at 4.5cm
- page numbers centered at 3.5 cm

I've succeeded to defined the margins with the `geometry` package but I'm struggling with the page numbers. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There are many ways -- even using "just" the `geometry` package -- of adjusting margin widths and other page-related parameters. Please consider editing your posting to show us an MWE (minimum working example) of what you've done so far and what you'd like to get done. As of now, your remark that you'd like to have the page numbers `at 3.5` isn't very specific: Do you want it centered, set flush-left, flush-right, at the bottom or top of the page, etc? Please be sure to indicate how big the physical page is (A4, US-Letter, something else?).

Comment: I did it with the `\setlength{\footskip}{}` in the `calc` package. Thanks anyway. Any other idea appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tricks will show that the dimensions you want can be obtained with the `geometry` package: two horizontal rules are visible at the top and at the bottom, at the page margins. In the final version, add also `heightrounded` to the setting of `geometry`; this will change a bit the top and bottom margin, but by a negligible amount.

```
\documentclass{article}

% set also left and right (or outer and inner for twoside printing)
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4.5cm,bottom=4.5cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}

% Don't do this in this document: it's just to show the bottom margin's size
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}%
  \smash{\vrule depth 3.5cm\vtop to3.5cm{\vfill\hbox{\vrule height 1pt width1cm}}}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode\smash{\vrule height \dimexpr4.5cm+\topskip\relax
  \vbox to \dimexpr4.5cm+\topskip\relax{\rlap{\vrule depth1pt height 0pt width 1cm}}}\kant

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll not use this for your document, the parts with `\smash` and so on are just to show that the dimensions are what expected.

### Top

[image]

### Bottom

[image]